# Отключить кэширование ID в PostgreSQL при удалении сущности?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Тестирую добавление с автоинкрементом в EFCore 6 с postgreSQL,

```
[Test]  
public IEnumerable<Student> GetNewStudents() 
{
    yield return new Student { StudentID = 1L, FirstName = "Abcd", LastName = "Efg" };
    yield return new Student { FirstName = "Hij", LastName = "Klmn" };
}
```

и следующий метод инкрементит айди на 1 у "Hij Klmn" каждый раз при удалении сущности, даже если её нету в базе ( у "Abcd Efg" айди остается тот же):

```
[Test]    
public void AddStudents()
{
    using (IDBContext dbContext = new MyDBContext())
    {
        foreach (var student in GetNewStudents())
        {
            dbContext.AddEntity(student);
        }
    }
}
```

То есть у "Hij Klmn"'s айди становится 2, потом 3, потом 4, и потом 5, хотя у меня всего 2 студента в базе.

Comment: Не очень ясен смысл теста. Вы тестируете, что в БД работает автоинкремент? Зачем?

Comment: @tym32167, я тестирую методы добавления сущностей в БД (без явного указания ID) с корректными (или некорректными) ID.

Comment: В чем вопрос то?

Comment: То есть вы тестируете работу бд? В чем смысл этого?

Comment: @aepot, вопрос в том, как отключить кэширование ID в базе данных на основе PostgreSQL, если я удалил сущность? У меня пустая база данных при добавлении сущности присваивает её ID = 6/ или 8, если я удалял существующие сущности и делал dbContext.SaveChanges(), хотя объекта в базе всего 2. Как отключить динамический инкремент ID в postgreSQL без указания ID сущности вручную? Она (postgresql или ef core6) считает присваивает новые ID объектам на основе тех объектов, которые уже стёрты из базы.

Comment: ID предназначены не для людей, они для машины! Оставьте машине копаться с циферками, а сами занимайтесь творчеством!

Comment: И хорошо, что ID увеличивается. Это гарантирует правильную работу многопоточного/многопроцессного кода. Иначе разные потоки могли бы получить сущности с одинаковыми айдишниками и при модификации/удалении их могла бы возникнуть неконсистентность БД. / Если какая-то СУБД выдаёт одинаковые ID разным сущностям - бегите от неё!